# Where is the shrine in the cut scene after Mipha's Grace?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

When you finish Mipha's dungeon, in the cut scene that plays where the Elephant goes and places itself before firing it's laser at Ganon, there's a shrine that can be seen.

I've looked high and low in Zora's domain, and couldn't find it or that kind of beach again.

So where is it?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the screenshot, that appears to be the Rucco Maag Shrine.  It is found due south of Zora's Domain across the Rutala River.  If you can't tell what it is, it's the one that's surrounded with spikes.  If you look close enough in my screenshots, you can see the dam in the background.

[image: Rucco Maag Shrine on map]

[image: Rucco Maag Shrine outside]

Comment: Oh! I never would have tought that this was the one in the cutscene, since I tought the clearing was a beach.

Answer (score 0):

If you warp to where the Divine Beast ends up and run to the edge of the mountain opposite Zora's domain you should be able to see it.

Haven't got the game map open for more precise directions, but there is a river running from the reservoir below the elephant and the shrine is on the other side. Fairly sure you can see it from Ruta's rock